# What's difference between reassure, soothe and settle down?

Tags: differences

I researched the meaning of this expressions in the Longman Dictionary and I found this:

**reassure**: to make someone feel calmer and less worried or frightened about a problem or situation

**soothe**: to make someone feel calmer and less anxious, upset, or angry

Both are related to make someone feel calmer. But I don't feel comfortable in them in a sentence.

I've tried to figure out and searched in the Internet the difference between them but I've not succeed.

Please, could someone help me out?

Comment: If there's a particular situation you need the right word for, e.g. a sentence where you are not sure whether to use "reassure" or "soothe", you should post that as part of your question.

Comment: You mention 'settle down' in your title but not your text. It is somewhat apart from the other two (different part of speech, different social situations). Do you really want to include it in your request for comparison?

Answer (score 2):

The definitions you give explain the difference: reassure refers to calming or de-stressing somebody who's worried about a situation or something happening in the future; soothe is more general and can refer to calming physical discomfort or other turbulence, and can be used of babies, animals, inflamed body parts, etc.

Oxford Dictionaries seems to have the most helpful examples for this. [Soothe](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/soothe): "a shot of brandy might soothe his nerves", "it contains a mild anaesthetic to soothe the pain". [Reassure](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/reassure): "he understood her feelings and tried to reassure her", "Joachim reassured him that he was needed".

To guide you:

1. The object of reassure is generally a person (older than a baby); soothe can take as an object babies, animals, body parts, medical conditions, or even inanimate objects like the sea.
2. Reassure can optionally take a "that" clause: you can reassure someone that something is the case, but you can't do that with "soothe".
3. You normally reassure someone about something (even if that's not stated explicitly in the sentence); it involves trying to convince somebody of something
4. You normally reassure with words; you can soothe with medicine, brandy, back-rubs, or other physical actions.